# Where do I find XamlReader?

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3, winapp

I'm trying to use XamlReader to create a FrameworkElement at runtime in a WinUI3 (WindowsApp) project.

There is documentation on how to do this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader?view=winrt-22621).

Unfortunately, the documentation is unclear about what nuget package contains XamlReader. The packages in my app are:

```
<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.WinUI" Version="7.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid" Version="7.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.Primitives" Version="7.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.2.230313.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.756" />
```

So which additional package do I need?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.markup?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a NuGet package. You might be missing the namespace:

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup;
```

I have a [video](https://youtu.be/3rZsIajf8h8) and a [sample app](https://github.com/AndrewKeepCoding/DynamicWinUI3SampleApp) using the `XamlReader`.

Comment: Thanx! But no I'm even more confused, because when I had included the Markup namespace yesterday XamlReader was not found...yet today I found it. It's possible I accidentally accepted inclusion of one of those stupid ABI.Microsoft namespaces which frequently gum up WinUI programming. I can't wait until they fix that by hiding what are, in fact, useless namespaces. I appreciate your help, and the example.

Comment: Great! I totally agree. Those ABI.Microsoft namespaces sneaking into (actually, we are letting them) code is very confusing sometimes.